# How to add images at the top of the chapter title

Tags: chapters

How to add images at the top of the chapter title. A sample snapshot like this(here circles are images):
[image]

The SWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
%  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\Huge\thechapter}
  {}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filcenter #1}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
%  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\Huge\thechapter}
  {}
  {1ex}
  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
      (-0.75cm,-2.5in)$) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};
      \vspace{1ex}\titlerule\\\filcenter #1
  }
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This attempt defines a macro called `\mychapter` where 3 pictures are added for each chapter. The location can be changed to suit one's need via `\put(x,y)` where the (0,0) is located at the lower left corner of a physical page. The current positions are manually set. `\AddToShipoutPicture` inserts the pictures onto the page when it is generated (i.e. at shipout.)

[image]

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wallpaper}  % Or \usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
%  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\Huge\thechapter}
  {}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filcenter #1}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{
\chapter{#1}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
\put(100,580){\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}}
\put(150,580){\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-b}}
\put(200,580){\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-c}}
}}


\begin{document}

\mychapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[4]

\section{blah blah blah}

\mychapter{The Second Chapter}
\lipsum[4]

\section{blah blah blah}

\mychapter{The third Chapter}
\lipsum[4]

\section{blah blah blah}
\end{document}
```