# Custom chapter with image

Tags: chapters, book-design

I would like to modify the `\chapter{}` command such that I can include a (fixed height) image in the following sense (quick sketch I made in LibreOffice) with an orange border around it:

[image]

Is this possible using TikZ?

//edit: Here is what I get (the aspect ratio is messed up, sure, but that will be OK later on because I will select a picture that works):

[image]

The MWE is here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\huge\bfseries}
  {\makebox[0cm][r]{\huge\bfseries}\thechapter.\hskip15pt}% label
  {0pt}
  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
  (0,-2cm)$) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=4cm]{example-image-a}};
  }
  []
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

There are the following problems:

- There is a weird line break between the chapter number and the title. Why?
- If I adjust the height of the image to be, say, 8cm, it will cover the chapter numbering etc. How can I make sure it is always *after* the end of the image?

Comment: Packages `titlesec`, or with `memoir` or change `\@makechapterhead` etc. No need for `TikZ`, in my point of view

Comment: Can you point me to a MWE?

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159978/how-to-add-images-at-the-top-of-the-chapter-title could help.

Comment: @samcarter: see my edited question above, it is almost what I want, but there are some issues.

Comment: Do you really need to draw the image using TiKz? Must it be a vector image? Is your book math/academic? Is your book an E-book? If the answer is `no` to all, then consider using the `novel` class. It specially deals with fixed-height chapter starts. But images must be raster grayscale for print to paper. You would create your image in (for example) GIMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `overlay`, the box will be essentially invisible to TeX as far as the space it occupies is concerned.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\huge\bfseries\printcurrentpicture}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\makebox[0cm][r]{\thechapter.\hspace{15pt}}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\newcommand{\printcurrentpicture}{%
  \vspace*{-\dimexpr\topskip+1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\lineskip}%
  \moveleft\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\vbox{%
    \hbox{%
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterpicture}%
    }
    \vspace{20pt}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\chapterpicture}[1]{%
  \def\thechapterpicture{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapterpicture{example-image-a}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

You'll have to define a suitable version for unnumbered chapters.

[image]